# Как подставлять .html в конце адреса страницы через .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Имеется адрес сайта со страницами вида:

- http://sitename.com/contacts/
- http://sitename.com/partners/

Как с помощью .htaccess привести URL к виду:

- http://sitename.com/contacts.html
- http://sitename.com/partners.html

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(\w*)/$ http://sitename.com/$1.html
```

Илит вот так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/$ http://sitename.com/$1.html [R]
```